# The constructor StringEntity(String, String, String) is deprecated

Tags: java

```
final org.apache.http.HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestStr, "text/xml", "UTF-8"); ...
```

The constructor `StringEntity(String, String, String)` is deprecated. Need some help resolving this deprecated method, Any idea or help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html#StringEntity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?

Comment: The javadoc suggests to use `StringEntity(String string,  ContentType contentType)`  instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html#StringEntity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) clearly states:

> Deprecated. (4.1.3) use [StringEntity(String, ContentType)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html#StringEntity(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.http.entity.ContentType))

So use this constructor instead.

**EDIT**: As was pointed out by @Arnaud, you can create your own content type through [`ContentType.create(String mimeType, Charset charset)`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html#create(java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: You can either set the content type or the character set. Not both.

Comment: Note that `ContentType` has a nice static method  that may help : `static ContentType create(String mimeType, String charset)`  .